# HTML Widget on many pages - Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have an HTML widget in the after-content section which will be displayed on 7 pages out of 12. I was reading up on it but didn't find anything except people mentioning rules, I went through the documentation and looked at using "or" rule with url("~/page1") like url("~/page2") or url("~/page3") so on. Will this not show all widgets on all pages? i just want to show one html widget at the bottom of many pages.

Thanks,
Adil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new layer "MyNewLayer" and then add your rule(s) there. Then, place the widget to be shown on this layer.